# Can't change the values of fields of model objects in lists

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why is it that when trying to set the value of a field of a model object contained in a list, the value doesn't get set, but when I store the object at that index into a variable, and *then* try to change it, I am successful? Below is an example of what I mean.

```
In [64]: profile[0].screen_name = "clutch"

In [65]: profile[0].screen_name

In [66]: p = profile[0]

In [67]: p.screen_name = "clutch"

In [68]: p.screen_name
Out[68]: 'clutch'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that profile in your case is not a list but a QuerySet. So every time you index it, it will execute the query against your database to get the object.

Try this before your code:

```
profile = list(profile)
```

That way the query executes and the results are now in a list.

Comment: I need to not make assumptions about the objects I'm working with ... type is my friend. Thanks!